# How to write and or in same query in mongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

How to write and or in same query in mongoDb ?
Say if I want to write below query in mongoDb how do I do that one.

```
select * from emp where (empid > 200 and dept_id=5) or dept_id <=4;
```

if collection holds below column

```
emp_id,emp_name,dept_id,sal
```

Comment: I would **strongly** suggest you spend some time going through this page: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

Answer (score 1):

```
db.emp.find({$or: [{$and: [{emp_id: {$gt: 200}}, {dept_id: 5}]}, {dept_id: {$lte: 4}}]})
```

read documents about comparison query operters [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/), and logical query operaters [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-logical/)

Comment: The $and would be considered redundant and as such not needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.coll.find({
    $or: [
        {
            $and: [
                {
                    emp_id: { $gt: 200 },
                },
                {
                    dept_id: 5
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            dept_id: { $lte: 4 }
        }
    ]
})
```

or more easy (in this case):

```
db.coll.find({
    $or: [
        {
            emp_id: { $gt: 200 },
            dept_id: 5
        }
        {
            dept_id: { $lte: 4 }
        }
    ]
})
```