# Mongodb find query using $or

Tags: mongodb, find

Please Help.
I am trying to create the query in mongodb like (in MySql):

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = '1' AND (type = 'admin' OR type = 'requester') ORDER BY user_id DESC
```

How do I convert this query into mongodb find({})?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write and or in same query in mongoDb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899364/how-to-write-and-or-in-same-query-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use **$in** instead of **$or** since only a single field is involved:

```
db.user.find({
    user_id:"1",
    type: {$in:["admin","requester"]}
}).sort({"user_id":-1});
```

Comment: Thanks Wake!
What if there are multiple fields in query like:

WHERE user_id = '1' and ('type' = 'admin' OR 'email' != 'abd@gmail.com')

Comment: That's where you'd use $or.  See the answer by cs_noob

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

```
db.user.find({user_id:"1",$or:[{"type":"admin"},{"type":"manager"}]})
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Actually I was trying to use query like:


{     $and : [         
{ $or : [ { isUserAcceptedAlternativeSlot : 'null' }, { acceptStatus : {$ne: "alternate" }}] },         
{ $and : [ { booked_by_user_id : "576a865bc0b8a9c01b35d608" } ] }     ] }

But null was accepting single quote in query. Without single quote, it was not giving correct result that I wanted.